# Defining a function to return members of a C++ enum definition, as part of a preprocessor macro?

Tags: c++, enumeration, boost-preprocessor

Given an enumeration defined as:

```
DEFINE_ENUM(name,enumerators)  \
enum name                                                              \
{                                                                      \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(enumerators)                                     \
};
```

How do I define a function which will be defined as part of the DEFINE_ENUM() macro and return a vector containing all members of the enumeration?

The following, added to the end of the macro definition above, is as close as I've come so far:

```
std::vector<name> MembersOf(name AnyItem) {     \
    return {BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(enumerators)}; \
};
```

This is reporting invalidly-terminated macro definitions, though, and claiming that every DEFINE_ENUM()'s MembersOf() is multiply defined if the file containing it is included in multiple files.

Comment: Just `return {BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(enumerators)};` and use the same list you do to create the enum.

Comment: I'm trying but failing to figure out how to get that to work -- I'm still learning C++11 features. Could you write that up as an answer, with the full source code I should be using?

Comment: That should be it given the same sequence parameter as `DEFINE_ENUM` takes. Vectors can be initialized with braced lists and braced initializers can be returned to construct the return type from.

Comment: remove `template<typename name>`, and (assuming C++11 support) do what @chris suggested.  Maybe add `(void)AnyItem;` statement to your function to avoid "unused parameter" warnings while you at it.

Comment: I removed the template (edited comment to reflect this -- thanks, both of you!), but I'm now getting linker errors -- MembersOf(), for all enumerations I'm using, is being regarded as multiply defined. Additionally, uses of DEFINE_ENUM() past the first in a file generate "improperly terminated macro invocation" warnings. I'm not sure how to address these, although they look related -- I'll update this if I figure it out...